# Cannot update mogodb object with axios.put in Mern stack app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I need to update my "comment" object from my mongodb database "comments" collection. More specifically, when I press the "Like" button, I want to send a put request with axios where I can add + 1 to the "likes" from "comment" object.

All other actions are working fine(getting comments, adding them, etc), the only one I'm struggling with is Updating the comment likes.

I would really appreciate if anybody can help. Thanks in advance!

Down here I added my code:

//--------CommentComponent.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { getComments, updateComment } from '../actions/commentActions'

const PostPage = ({ match }) => {
    
const commentz = useSelector(store => store.comment.comments)
const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getComments())
}, [dispatch])

const handleLike = e => {
    dispatch(updateComment(e.target.id))
}

return (
    {commentz ? commentz.map(comm => 
        comm.forWich === match.params.id ?
            <div key={comm._id} className={styles.comment}>
                <div>
                    <h2>{comm.name}</h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                     <p>{comm.comment}</p>
                </div>
                     {comm.likes} <button id={comm} onClick={handleLike}>Like</button>
                <div>
            </div>
        : null
    ) : null}
    )
}

export default PostPage
```

//-------Comment.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    forWich: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Comment = mongoose.model('comment', CommentSchema);
```

//-------comments.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Comments Model
const Comment = require('../../models/Comment');

// @route UPDATE api/comments
// @desc Update comment
// @access Public
router.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    Comment.findbyId(req.params.id)
       .then(comment => comment.update(req.body))
       .catch(next);
})

module.exports = router;
```

//--------CommentActions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { 
    GET_COMMENTS,
    ADD_COMMENTS,
    COMMENTS_LOADING,
    GO_COMMENTS,
    UPDATE_COMMENTS
} from './types';



export const updateComment = comment => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios
            .put(`/api/comments`, comment)
            .then(res =>
                dispatch({
                    type: UPDATE_COMMENTS,
                    payload: comment
                })
            )
    }
}
```

//--------CommentReducer.js

```
import {
    GET_COMMENTS,
    ADD_COMMENTS,
    COMMENTS_LOADING,
    GO_COMMENTS,
    UPDATE_COMMENTS
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    comments: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case UPDATE_COMMENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                comments: state.comments.map(comm => comm._id === action.payload._id ? comm.likes = action.payload + 1 : comm.likes)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed things a little bit:

1. The Comment model "likes" became an array of objects, so I can store the Id of the comment, the visitor's Id that liked the comment(wich will get created on page load, with the help of localStorage) and the date when the like button was clicked:

**models/Comment.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    likes: [
        {
            commentId: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            userId: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }
    ],
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    forWich: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Comment = mongoose.model('comment', CommentSchema);
```

2. Route changed, from "put" to "post", so I'm adding an entire object, instead of concatenating a number:

**routes/api/comments:**

```
router.post('/like', (req, res) => {
    const { commentId, userId } = req.body;
    Comment.findById(commentId)
    .then(comment => {
        comment.likes.unshift({ commentId, userId });
        comment.save().then(comment => res.json(comment));

    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(404).json({ commentnotfound: "No comment found" })
    });
});
```

3. Redux action, I changed "handleLike" to "addLike"

**actions/commentActions.js:**

```
export const addLike = ({ commentId, userId }) => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        const body = JSON.stringify({ commentId, userId });

        axios.post(`/api/comments/like`, body, config)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(getComments())
            }
        )
    }
};
```

...as you can see, there isn't any payload attributed to any type, so no need to use UPDATE_COMMENTS anymore, so no reducer either.

4. Finally, the front-end, where at page load, I'm using localStorage to assing an Id to a new client. Based on that Id, I'm creating a new like object:

**PostPage.js:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem(`userId`)) {
        localStorage.setItem(`userId`, uuidv4())
    }
}, [])

const handleLike = e => {
    e.preventDefault()        
    if(localStorage.getItem(`userId`)) {
        const newLike = {
            commentId: e.target.value,
            userId: localStorage.getItem(`userId`)
        }
        dispatch(addLike(newLike))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
Comment.findById()
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

Answer (score 0):

Your put request on the client needs to be something like:

```
axios.get(`/api/comments/${comment.id}` comment)
```